# Virtuemart Checkout force user to register to allow gift coupon usage

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I am using virtuemart 2.6.6 with Joomla 2.5.

I have added gift coupons for users and I want them to use this once when placing their first order. The problem is that when a user is not registered they will try to add the coupon code FREEDEL at site localbutler.co.uk but the one page checkout page first prompts them to add their details and then proceeds to confirm their order but not give the user an opportunity to add the code.

Is there any way that I can force users to register first and then automatically login before the page showing the cart item appears because when a user is previously registered the coupon works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue.

I edited the cart php files and inserted the following code:

```
//JUMP ADDRESS CODE

$user = JFactory::getUser();
$status = $user->guest;

if($status == 1){
echo "not logged in";
goto out_a;
}
else
{ 
echo "logged in";

}   
?>
```

I know that using goto is not a great way of coding in php but it allowed me to jump over displaying the address fields when the user was not logged in.